# Distributed mongo in windows

Tags: windows, mongodb

How to configure distributed mongodb installation in windows?........

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP and MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can install mongodb on Windows as service, for example:

- download mongodb: http://www.mongodb.org/downloads
- Unzip into c:\mongo
- create dir c:\mongo\data
- create file: c:\mongo\config.txt

  dbpath = c:\mongo\data

  bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

  noauth = true
- install as windows service from command prompt

  C:> c:\mongo\bin\mongod.exe -f c:\mongo\config.txt --logpath c:\mongo\log.txt --install
- start service

  C:> net start mongodb

As for distributed installation, there should not be anything Wondows specific. Just follow the documentation ([Replication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication) and [Sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding)) and change your configurations for your needs.